# How can I make a javascript file to a valid https url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, cdn

Let say my javascript file name is downloader.js and I want to make it like below:

```
https://<somedomain>/downloader.js
```

This Javascript file will be used by a chrome extension. The chrome extension needs a valid https URL for the javascript file.

Comment: Ideally, you will want to obtain an SSL (as I see this might be what you mean by one of your comments). I would contact your hosting provider or domain registrar to see if they can sell you one. Most do.

Comment: Is there a service where I can upload my js file and they will give me a https url?

Comment: You could just place the js file into google drive and share it. Here is a description of how that works: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970 However that service will be discontinued in august next year so you need to find another place to put it before then.

Comment: Thank you @spiderpig. Let me read this up.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register a domain name, that is where you choose what you want to use, for example "example.com".  When you register the name, you purchase it and it is yours.

Once you have a domain name, you can set up hosting.  In many cases a shared hosting account will suffice.  Setting up hosting means you are leasing space on a server where the files for your web site will be.

Once you have a domain name and hosting, place downloader.js in DocumentRoot.

If you don't already have HTTPS, check with your hosting company.

Comment: I don't have https in my site. I want to host it to somewhere.